# Having description and contact at Mercurial web page

Tags: mercurial, sourceforge

Currently, I am in the progress of migrating CVS to Mercurial.

http://jstock.hg.sourceforge.net/hgweb/jstock/

I would like to have contact and description information in the mercurial page.

I look at https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/PublishingRepositories#Putting_useful_information_in_the_index_page

But, it seems that, modification on `C:\Projects\jstock\.hg\hgrc` doesn't have any effect at all. `push` will not update anything in sourceforge server.

So, does this mean the only way is to remote access to sourceforge mercurial server and modify the hgrc file manually?

I try to ssh to the remote machine.

```
[yccheok@shell-22003 .hg]$ pwd
/home/scm_hg/j/js/jstock/jstock-cloud/.hg
[yccheok@shell-22003 .hg]$ ls -al
total 56
drwxrwsr-x 3 yccheok jstock 1024 Nov 30 15:29 .
drwxrwsr-x 3 yccheok jstock   80 Nov 30 15:13 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 yccheok jstock   57 Nov 30 15:13 00changelog.i
-rw-rw-r-- 1 yccheok jstock   93 Nov 30 15:29 branchheads.cache
-rw-rw-r-- 1 yccheok jstock   23 Nov 30 15:13 requires
drwxrwsr-x 3 yccheok jstock 1024 Nov 30 15:29 store
-rw-rw-r-- 1 yccheok jstock  317 Nov 30 15:29 tags.cache
-rw-rw-r-- 1 yccheok jstock    7 Nov 30 15:29 undo.branch
-rw-rw-r-- 1 yccheok jstock    0 Nov 30 15:29 undo.dirstate
[yccheok@shell-22003 .hg]$
```

But not able to find `hgrc` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.hg/hgrc` file contains **local settings** and is not itself a versioned file. These settings do not travel from one repository to the other by `hg clone`, `hg push` or `hg pull` commands.

If you want to edit the `hgrc` file of your source forge repository, you have to use Sourceforge's [interactive shell service](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/sourceforge/wiki/Shell%20service).

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the sourceforge server doesn't consider your repo's `.hg/hgrc` file due to [trust rules](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Trust).  Their webserver user would need to have a trust block saying they trust .hgrc files from you, which is a risk as it allows you to have code executed as their webserver user.

If there's a way to do this the solution is going to come from somewith with strong sourceforge-fu, not mercurial-fu.

Comment: The trust rules only apply when two users use the same local repository (e.g. give each other permission to read home directory, share folder over samba, NFS folder). The OP is accessing a remote repository over http.